# Ошибка C2679 («не найден оператор...»)

Tags: c++, vector, итераторы

Сохраняю с CSV файла в вектор. После этого нужно вывести 5 случайных людей:

```
vector<vector<string>> Man;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    auto  k = rand() % Man.size();

    for (auto l = Man[k].begin(); l < Man[k].end(); l++) {
        cout << Man[k][l] << " ";                             // ←——— тут ошибка
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Ошибка:

```
C2679    бинарный "[": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)   Project9    c:\users\ost1m1ron\source\repos\project9\project9\source.cpp    107
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка? Приведите полный текст ошибки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь получить значение отправляя в `operator[]` не индекс(`size_t`), а итератор!!

Когда вы пишите `auto l = Man[k].begin()`, это и есть итератор на конкретный элемент, т.е. чтобы получить данные достаточно просто разыменовать итератор.

```
vector<vector<string>> Man;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    auto  k = rand() % Man.size();
    for (auto l = Man[k].begin(); l < Man[k].end(); ++l)
    {
        cout << *l << " "; // SUPERMAN
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Пару советов:

1. Используйте префиксный инкремент (`++i`, а не `i++`). Это **особенно** касается невстроенных типов.
2. Вы пишите в условии цикла `l < Man[k].end()`. Вы на каждой итерации вызываете `Man::operator[]` и `end()`. Лучше будет получить перед внутренним циклом значение `end()` и дальше сравнивать. И сравнивать не `оператором<` а `оператором!=`.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: оффтоп но как искать по первой букве имени через итератор

Comment: @ost1m1ron-, например так: `(*l)[0]` - вернет первый символ строки

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (auto l = Man[k].begin(); l < Man[k].end(); l++) {
     cout << Man[k][l] << " "; 
 }
l  это итератор и нельзя его использовать как индекс.
Поэтому нужно поменять на:

for (auto l = Man[k].begin(); l != Man[k].end(); l++) {
    cout << *l << " "; 
}
```

Comment: итераторы с произвольным доступом, коим и является итератор вектора, обеспечивают оператор меньше

Comment: Спасибо,что напомнили